# asp.net server tags not working inside an iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server-tags

my server tags are not being converted inside the for iteration.
Have a look down bellow.

```
<% for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
{ %>
   <option value="<%=i%>">
   <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%=i%> <%$ Resources:Titles, dias%>"></asp:Literal></option>
<% } %>
<option selected="selected" value="30">
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="30 <%$ Resources:Titles, dias%>"></asp:Literal></option>
```

above is my line of code, and its not working like it should because the result is down bellow:

```
<select id="ddlPeriodoCrescimento" style="color: black !important; height: 23px !important; margin:auto !important" onchange="loadCadastros()">    
    <option value="1">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="2">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="3">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="4">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="5">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="6">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="7">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="8">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="9">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="10">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="11">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="12">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="13">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="14">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="15">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="16">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="17">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="18">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="19">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="20">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="21">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="22">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="23">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="24">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="25">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="26">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="27">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="28">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option value="29">
        &lt;%=i%&gt; &lt;%$ Resources:Titles, dias%&gt;</option>

    <option selected="selected" value="30">
        30 Dias</option>
</select>
```

Why is not converting the servers tags <% %> inside the for iteration? any reason, am i forgetting something or is it a bug?
if it is a bug any solution to work around it?

Comment: That is why there is something called a Repeater Control.  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: You may want to look into ASP.NET MVC and Razor if you want to do these kind of things very often.

Comment: `<option>` tags cannot contain any markup... just text, thats a basic Html thing though not a .net thing

Comment: zgood, the asp.net compiler compiles the page before it gets to the client side, the last option is working with the server tag. 
this tags are not ordinary tags, html don't handle them.